# Error with dll when importing Qt Desktop Components for PySide

Tags: qml, pyside

I am trying to get Qt Quick Desktop Components to work with PySide 1.1.2 and Python 2.7. So far, I have compiled the latest version of the Desktop Components with MSVC in release mode and copied the components folder, containing both the .qml files and plugin/styleplugin.dll, to Python\Lib\site-packages\PySide\imports\QtDesktop.

Here is my current code:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtDeclarative import QDeclarativeView

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
view = QDeclarativeView()

view.setSource(QUrl('server.qml'))
view.setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView.SizeRootObjectToView)
view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My Qml file:

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import QtDesktop 0.1

Window {
}
```

The error I am getting:

```
file:///C:/Programming/CibAbi/server.qml:15:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtDesktop":
 Cannot load library C:/Programming/Python27_32bit/Lib/site-packages/PySide/imports/QtDesktop/plugin/styleplugin.dll:
 The specified procedure could not be found.
 import QtDesktop 0.1
 ^
```

Does anybody know of a way to fix this, or does anyone have more specific steps on using the Desktop Components with PySide? Thank you. :)

Comment: If you ever solved this problem I'd love to hear a solution. I've been trying everything for a long time and can't get past what you've posted here.

Comment: @Carrotman Nope, I never did manage to find a solution and in the end, the project I was working on didn't need this. I'd suggest using PyQt if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your system PATH variable so that the PySide directory appears in the path before any PyQt or other Qt directory.

http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_FAQ#6624847b60a84a6d81a5950805dfb6df

Comment: Thanks, but this was not it. PyQt is not installed, nor is any other Qt directory located before the PySide directory in the PATH variable.

Comment: Try running sysinternals procmon while you recreate the error and look for events with status != success. You're basically looking for an incompatible dll load, or missing path component that you can add to your path environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

works perfectly
pyside py 3.3 32 Bit
Qt libraries 4.8.5 for Windows (VS 2010)

config release and build

rename folder "component" to "QtDesktop"
copy this folder en pyside/imports/

and Guala